# Find if data in column fulfills a datatype condition in sql

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradatasql

I have a table product with a column product id which is string datatype as below.

```
Product_id
101 
102
102a
```

I would like to know if there is any way to take all values in product_id which cannot fill the condition of integer which is 102a value as it cannot be converted to integer

Query something like

```
select product_id from product where product_id <> integer
```

And output should be as

| Product_id |
| --- |
| 102a |

Comment: you have named 3 DB's which one are you wanting this for?

Comment: Any one if them would be fine teradata and snowflake preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In snowflake:

```
select column1 as Product_id
from values 
    ('101'),
    ('102'),
    ('102a')
where try_to_number(Product_id) is null;
```

gives

| PRODUCT_ID |
| --- |
| 102a |

[TRY_TO_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_decimal.html) will return null, if the input string fails to convert, thus, you could use that in your WHERE clause.

If you want a REGEX form, you can use:

```
where rlike(Product_id, '.*\\D.*')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex like here:

```sql
SELECT Product_id
FROM product
WHERE Product_id !~ '\D';
```

This would return only records having `Product_id` values *not* having any non digit characters (i.e. the characters it does have are all digits).

Comment: Thanks but i am unable to run  in teradata is it different with other db? Pls help

Comment: In Teradata you could use `TRYCAST(Product_id AS INTEGER)` or `REGEXP_SIMILAR(Product_id,'.*\D.*') = 0` or `REGEXP_SUBSTR(Product_id,'\D') IS NULL`